# Selecting Text in a QTreeWidgetItem with the cursor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to find a way of selecting QtGui.QTreeWidget.QTreeWidgetItem.text(1) with the cursor.

```
if column == 1:
    # Makes Row editable
    item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)

    # Select item to edit
    Xitem = self.treewidget.editItem(item, column)

    # Makes Row uneditable
    item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```

I know that, by default, all the text will be selected. However, because I'm enabling editing then disabling editing is results with the text being unselected.

*Why are you enabling and disabling edibility?*
I have it set up so that you can only edit the text of 1 column, out of several. However, simply turning on ItemIsEditable will make **all** columns editable, i just wanted the one specific column, so i immediately have to disable it again.

Knock on effect, it deselects the text in the desired column. I can still edit it, it's just deselected.

So i want to ctrl+a selected all.
I've been trying to work out how to do this for a while, but am getting no where.

Methods for getting my desired results would be running the ctrl+a hotkey through python code, or working out how to get the QTextCursor stuff to work with the QTreeWidgetItem.

```
editor = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.treewidget)
cursor = editor.textCursor()
cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.Start, QtGui.QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
editor.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

I feel like i'm close, but am just missing something here :/

Comment: Your description of the problem seens very confused. Please provide a [mcve] and state clearly what behaviour you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution to this, although I couldn't workout how to select all text I was able to clean up my script to get the desired result:

```
def checkEditFUNC(self, item, column):
    '''
    Allows editing of certain items in the table
    :param item: item name
    :param column: Column number
    '''

    # To allow editing only in column 1 and 2
    if column == 1:
        # Makes Row editable
        item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
    else:
        item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
```